# Injecting a new ZWJ emoji into an existing TTF font?

Tags: fonts, emoji

Is it feasible for me to write code that takes an SVG (or other vector image) of a new emoji and inject it into my system’s emoji font (eg. `Apple Colour Emoji.ttf`), so that an unused emoji + ZWJ + emoji combination now shows my custom emoji? (For as long as my system doesn’t update it’s font file)

A while back I tried using some font tools and a hex editor to inspect how my Mac’s emoji font works, and discovered how there seems to be full turning complete subsystems *inside the font* for selecting the right glyph from the byte sequence provided.

Obviously, with right to left glyphs, skin tone modifiers and all the other immense complexity of font content that bytecode seemed complex enough that I put that project idea down.

Putting aside the “should I?”, is there a code-based method simple enough for me to be able to inject a totally new glyph and assign it to a ZWJ linked cluster of my choosing? (I’m sure there are GUIs that could do this, but I’d be interested in writing code to do this, to learn more about how fonts work on the inside!)